# Laravel Schedule withoutOverlapping() is not working with runInBackground()

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-6

I'm trying to setup schedule for my commands in `/app/Console/Kernel.php` and found out that `withoutOverlapping()` doesnt work with `runInBackground()`

This works without overlaps:

```
$schedule
    ->command('test:update')
    ->withoutOverlapping();
```

This overlaps tasks:

```
$schedule
    ->command('test:update')
    ->withoutOverlapping()
    ->runInBackground();
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, you're correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, it was working without overlaps because command was running in the foreground and scheduler was busy processing this command thus didn't run new one until current command finished. `withoutOverlapping()` did not impact anything here.

So the problem was that the mutex is not being created with`withoutOverlapping()`. Laravel scheduler is using cache for mutex. Switching cache driver to redis helped fix this issue, now `withoutOverlapping()` works as it should.