# My Laravel Schedule withoutOverlapping() is not working with runInBackground()

Tags: laravel-5.7

I saw that someone else was having the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60324548/laravel-schedule-withoutoverlapping-is-not-working-with-runinbackground/61431511#61431511) but when I tried their solution it still does not seem to work.

I am running Laravel 5.7

I have set redis as my cache:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
```

but in database.php do I need to edit anything?

```
    'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],
```

I have done:

```
composer install predis/predis
```

I can confirm that redis is working:

```
KEYS *
  1) "laravel:framework/schedule-3032780d7b5657bd5e6ba0fef1359f330895c3da"
```

I have 15 tasks that run at different times but it seems the first one runs but the others after it do not.

```
$schedule->command( 'do:task one' )->cron( '1/3 * * * *' )->withoutOverlapping()->runInBackground();
$schedule->command( 'do:task two' )->cron( '1/5 * * * *' )->withoutOverlapping()->runInBackground();
$schedule->command( 'do:task three' )->cron( '1/15 * * * *' )->withoutOverlapping()->runInBackground();
```

Has anybody else come across this?

Thanks